# Submit Buttons Only Work Sometimes on iPhone - CSS Issue?

Tags: jquery, css, iphone, wordpress

I'm installing Stripe Checkout on my Wordpress site, and mostly things are going smoothly.

However, I'm finding that the buttons on my page which are supposed to launch the Checkout process are only working intermittently on iPhone (Safari and Chrome).

Here's the page:

http://www.radionowhere.net/kit/

(the buttons actually say "Get My CD!")

I'm finding that sometimes the buttons work immediately when clicked, sometimes they need to be clicked 4 or 5 times. I had to do a bunch of CSS fiddling to get these right, so I suspect there might be some weirdness in there that's causing the problem, but I can't find it.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Add some of your code for more help

Comment: SO won't let me paste the relevant code here, but this is a link: http://www.radionowhere.net/wp-content/themes/holi/css/page-kit.css

Comment: The deal is that (according to Firebug) button CSS for the theme is overriding button CSS from Stripe Checkout, so in the CSS file linked above, I attempted to override the relevant theme code. Didn't quite pull it off, obviously, but again not sure where I went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get access to that CSS this may be a way to override it:

```
.stripe-button-el:not(:disabled):active,.stripe-button-el.active { 
visibility: initial !important;
 } 

 .stripe-button-el:not(:disabled):active span,.stripe-button-el.active span {
visibility: initial !important;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have control over the button; it's generated by the Stripe Checkout code.

Comment: That's your problem can't you modify the class "stripe-button-el" and just remove the hover, active, etc. states in the CSS?  Another thing you can do is test to see if the button is working by adding JavaScript onclick="alert('CLICKED')"   after the class and if it fails we know it's the CSS causing problems.

Comment: Just tried adding ".stripe-button-el" to my page-kit.css stylesheet; however, it is overridden by the theme code for buttons. I'm really confused as to the way CSS rules priority is working on this page.

Comment: I understand your confusion bootstrap has some CSS that out of the box needs to be overridden. First your page-kit.css needs to load after the sheet using .stripe-button-el.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I have no idea how to do that. When you view page source, there isn't even any reference to a STripe stylesheet, just .js . I know a little about CSS, but nothing about javascript, or how to dictate the order of stylesheet loading. Here's a link to a page where the button works as intended (the Pay With Card button): https://stripe.com/docs/checkout .

Comment: Question. Have you tried adding the javascript alert to test the button? Try it with and without the class on your iPhone.

I understand your confusion bootstrap has some CSS that out of the box needs to be overridden. First your page-kit.css needs to load after the sheet using .stripe-button-el. What you need to do is reference all the classes you want to overrride. So if the button has button:hover and button:active then you need to cancel out the elements that are causing the problem. For example if it says margin:5px and that's causing the problem you would use margin:0px.

Comment: One other thing. Your site looks it was created with (cough cough) Wordpress it's calling a bunch of CSS files. There is one called button.css that I think is the problem, and it's called multiple times. You have two classes .stripe-button-el:not(:disabled):active,.stripe-button-el.active
{

}
.stripe-button-el:not(:disabled):active span,.stripe-button-el.active span
{

If you remove them it might fix the problem.

Comment: The plugin is generating the CSS, based on a shortcode I'm entering in page HTML. So I don't think I can include a javascript alert. I can't figure out how to place my overrides last in the cascade. For instance, just as a test, right now the last entry in my page-kit.css is ".stripe-button-el {visibility: hidden !important;}". But the Stripe CSS is overriding that. How can I fix this?

Comment: Looks like our comments crossed each other. button.css is generated by Stripe Checkout, so I can't access/remove it

Comment: My initial problem (see top of this page), which I'd solved with CSS tweaks, has now cropped up again on another webpage - http://www.radionowhere.net/2up/ - this page uses the same Stripe shortcode as my other page, and I copied the external CSS that had been working on my original page. Now, on /2up/, using Safari on an iPhone 5, I can't successfully push the button to launch Stripe checkout. Works on Chrome, though. So I suspect it's (somehow) a CSS issue. Any ideas? Thanks!